# Image crop, resize and compression plugin?

Tags: plugins, images

I've been looking through the plugins to find one that will allow the user to resize & crop images within WP.

This has been the one area that clients struggle with - mainly those who don't have any photo editing software on their computers.

Also, if there's one that deals with some kind of image compression options then that would be great as some clients have put some huge images on pages.

Has anyone got any pointers or experience with any of the plugins out there to do this?

**Update:**

Image rotation would be nice too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has cropping and resizing and rotation built in.

Tutorial: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-crop-rotate-scale-and-flip-images-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You can try [WP Paint](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-paint/), which is a free WordPress image editor plugin, with this you can easily crop, resize, add texts, shapes, gradient and more to your images. It automatically compresses the image size too without compromising on the image quality.

You can read about the detailed comparison between the [WordPress Image Editors.](https://zonewp.com/2019/09/comparison-of-3-best-wordpress-image-editor-plugins/)